# Saving formset related models by multi-room relationships in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Please tell me how to save a formset with two models related to the manytomanyfield relationship, it turns out while two forms are displayed when the page is opened, after filling in and clicking on the "Add" button, the "phone" and "client_name" fields are cleared and the form is not sent. In view class OrderCreateView(CreateView), checking client_formset.is_valid() returns False.

Here is the code:

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Client(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Телефон')
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='ФИО клиента')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.phone, self.client_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Клиент'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Клиенты'


class Order(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Принял', blank=True)
    date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
    execution_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата исполнения')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Адрес')
    service = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Услуга')
    master = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='master', null=True, verbose_name='Мастер', blank=True)
    client = models.ManyToManyField(Client, verbose_name='Клиент', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.execution_date, self.address, self.service)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Заявка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заявки'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
# from .models import Orders, Person, Phone
from .models import Order, Client
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import modelformset_factory


class UserFullnameChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_full_name()


class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    master = UserFullnameChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), label='Мастер')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('execution_date', 'address', 'service', 'master')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['master'].empty_label = '-Выберите мастера-'
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'


# Form for clients
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label='Телефон', required=True)
    client_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='ФИО клиента', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['phone', 'client_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'


# Formset for clients
ClientFormSet = modelformset_factory(Client, form=ClientForm, extra=1)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Order, Client
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .forms import OrderForm, AuthUserForm, RegisterUserForm, ClientForm
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.forms import modelformset_factory


class OrderCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    form_class = OrderForm
    template_name = 'create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('data_base')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ClientFormSet = modelformset_factory(Client, form=ClientForm, extra=1)
        context['client_formset'] = ClientFormSet(queryset=Client.objects.none())
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        client_formset = context['client_formset']
        if form.is_valid() and client_formset.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            for client_form in client_formset:
                if client_form.cleaned_data:
                    client = client_form.save(commit=False)
                    client.order = self.object
                    client.save()

            form.save()

            return super().form_valid(form)

        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, client_formset=client_formset))
```

create.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Создать заявку
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Creating an application</h1>

{% if success %}
<p class="text-success">Заявка добавлена</p>
{% elif success == False %}
<p class="text-danger">Ошибка</p>
{% endif %}

<form id="add_form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}

    <div id="client-fields">
        {% for form in client_formset %}
        <div class="client-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.client_name.id_for_label }}">ФИО клиента</label>
                {{ form.client_name }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{ form.phone.id_for_label }}">Телефон</label>
                {{ form.phone }}
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="remove-client">Delete</button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="add-client-field">Add client</button>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
        <button form="add_form" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add-client-field').click(function() {
      var clientField = $('#client-fields .client-form:first').clone(true);
      // Clear the field values in the new field
      clientField.find('input').val('');
      clientField.find('input[name*=client_name]').attr('name', 'client_name_' + $('#client-fields .client-form').length);
      clientField.find('input[name*=phone]').attr('name', 'phone_' + $('#client-fields .client-form').length);
      clientField.insertAfter('#client-fields .client-form:last');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove-client', function() {
      if ($('#client-fields .client-form').length > 1) {
        $(this).closest('.client-form').remove();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

this is all so that when creating an application, you can add several clients with phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a relation to an object that has not yet been saved. So you have to save `self.object` before processing `client_form`.

Provided you are in a transaction, if anything goes wrong (that raises an unhandled exception) the object will be un-saved (or rather, the database transaction will not be committed)

Try this

```
from django.db import transaction
...

if form.is_valid() and client_formset.is_valid():
    with transaction.atomic():

        self.object = form.save()
        for client_form in client_formset:
            if client_form.cleaned_data:
                client = client_form.save(commit=False)
                client.order = self.object
                client.save()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, everything is the same